# Is it possible to create a python vitualenv using a standalone jython jar as EXE?

Tags: jython, virtualenv

I know jython can be used as the python interpreter for a virtualenv. Simple as:

```
 virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/jython jython-env --no-site-packages
```

Let's say I didn't want to install jython at all but instead use a standalone jar as the python interpreter for the vitualenv. Is this possible?

Using

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Java OpenJDK 1.6
- Jython Standalone 2.5.3 jar

Comment: I did. But the jar isn't executable. It uses java to call it. `virtualenv` gave me an error. Something like "The executable is not executable"